# How to use legends in matlab with for loop and hold on command?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, plot, legend

I am using MATLAB to plot a graph. The task is to read three variables from files in FOR loop, read variables, plot figure (1) (var1 vs var2), hold the plot, save it; plot figure (2) (var1 vs Var3) hold the plot save it. Open another file, read three variables and repeat ploting on same page! Now there are 25 such files in a folder which will be plotted using different colors but on same plot. like all var1 and var2 on one page. My problem is in giving legends for all 25 plots of var1 vs var2. I have written a sample code, but legends are not showing. Anybody would like to help me in solving the issue!

My code is as follows:

```
clc
clear 
close all
colormap jet;
%cmap=colormap;
cmap = [jet(2); jet(2)];
curve_legends1 = cell(25, 1);
curve_legends2 = cell(25, 1);

files=cellstr(ls('*.txt'));
for kk=1:length(files)
     file1=files{kk};
   [pathstr,name,ext] = fileparts(file1);


startRow = 2;
formatSpec = '%15s%15s%15s%15s%15s%15s%15s%15s%15s%15s%15s%15s%15s%15s%s%[^\n\r]';
%% Open the text file.
fileID = fopen(file1,'r');
dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', '', 'WhiteSpace', '', 'HeaderLines' ,startRow-1, 'ReturnOnError', false);
%% Close the text file.
fclose(fileID);

raw = repmat({''},length(dataArray{1}),length(dataArray)-1);
for col=1:length(dataArray)-1
    raw(1:length(dataArray{col}),col) = dataArray{col};
end
numericData = NaN(size(dataArray{1},1),size(dataArray,2));

for col=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
    % Converts strings in the input cell array to numbers. Replaced non-numeric
    % strings with NaN.
    rawData = dataArray{col};
    for row=1:size(rawData, 1);
        % Create a regular expression to detect and remove non-numeric prefixes and
        % suffixes.
        regexstr = '(?<prefix>.*?)(?<numbers>([-]*(\d+[\,]*)+[\.]{0,1}\d*[eEdD]{0,1}[-+]*\d*[i]{0,1})|([-]*(\d+[\,]*)*[\.]{1,1}\d+[eEdD]{0,1}[-+]*\d*[i]{0,1}))(?<suffix>.*)';
        try
            result = regexp(rawData{row}, regexstr, 'names');
            numbers = result.numbers;

            % Detected commas in non-thousand locations.
            invalidThousandsSeparator = false;
            if any(numbers==',');
                thousandsRegExp = '^\d+?(\,\d{3})*\.{0,1}\d*$';
                if isempty(regexp(thousandsRegExp, ',', 'once'));
                    numbers = NaN;
                    invalidThousandsSeparator = true;
                end
            end
            % Convert numeric strings to numbers.
            if ~invalidThousandsSeparator;
                numbers = textscan(strrep(numbers, ',', ''), '%f');
                numericData(row, col) = numbers{1};
                raw{row, col} = numbers{1};
            end
        catch me
        end
    end
end


%% Replace non-numeric cells with NaN
R = cellfun(@(x) ~isnumeric(x) && ~islogical(x),raw); % Find non-numeric cells
raw(R) = {NaN}; % Replace non-numeric cells

data = cell2mat(raw);

alt = data(:, 1);
altkm = alt/1000
h2o = data(:, 2);
o2 = data(:, 3);

figure(1)
Plot_color=cmap(kk/1,:);           
plot(h2o,altkm,'Color', Plot_color);
curve_legends1{kk+1} = ['LT = ' num2str(kk+1)];
ylim([0  110]);
hold on
s=[name];
ii=sscanf(s,'fig1_H2O_%f',[1,inf])'
saveas(gca,sprintf('fig1_H2O_%d.pdf',(ii)))

figure(2)
Plot_color=cmap(kk/1,:);           
plot(o2,altkm,'Color', Plot_color);
curve_legends2{kk+1} = ['LT = ' num2str(kk+1)];
ylim([0  110]);
hold on
s=[name];
ii=sscanf(s,'fig2_O2S_%f',[1,inf])'
saveas(gca,sprintf('fig2_O2_%d.pdf',(ii)))

end

%% Clear temporary variables
clearvars filename startRow formatSpec fileID dataArray ans;
```

Answer (score 1):

You construct yourself a legend string via

```
curve_legends1{kk+1} = ['LT = ' num2str(kk+1)];
```

and

```
curve_legends2{kk+1} = ['LT = ' num2str(kk+1)];
```

respectively, but you never apply it. At first sight it seems this is missing only a call to the `legend` function. Not sure which one goes where but I guess a `legend(curve_legends1{kk+1})` (after the first assignment) and `legend(curve_legends2{kk+1})` (after the second assignment) would do something of the sort you might need. By the way, not sure why you use `kk+1` here as `kk` seems to be running from 1. So you're skipping the first element of the cell array.

Comment: I will implement it an will let you know !

Answer (score 0):

I have manually defined legends, after the plot function.
I have achieved using the command as written below. This helped me. Thanks everyone for advice.

```
legend('LT = 0.125','LT = 1.125',........ and so on);
.
.
%adding the code before the loop ends (^_^)

legend('show')
end
```